# onPause() function does not work when extend MapActivity

Tags: java, android, mapactivity

When I extend MapActivity instead of Activity, I can not use onPause(), onResume(), onRestart() functions. When I create protected void onPause(), there is an error for force close when I click home button. I tried ActivityGroup and it doesn't work too. What should I do?

Comment: What is the error you get on force close?

Comment: "the application *** (process com.esetron.client) has stoped unexpectedly. Please try again later". If I don't use onResume, onPause functions, I don't get such an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you forget to call `super.onPause()`, `super.onResume()`, etc.?

Quote from the documentation:

> Derived classes must call through to the super class's implementation
>   of this method. If they do not, an exception will be thrown.

Comment: No, I didn't forget super.onPause(). Since I extend MapActivity, compiler gives error on super.onPause() line.

Comment: That makes no sense. Of course you can override MapActiviy.onPause(). What error is the compiler giving you?

Comment: I don't know why but I made it work. I did project-> clean on eclipse and it worked :S

Comment: Great. Glad you solved your problem. Eclipse is a nightmare :-(